# Get required data from html source of website

Tags: php, regex, json, preg-match

I'm reading source code of this link [Source](http://www.dresslink.com/women-round-neck-sleeveless-backless-padded-stretch-solid-short-fitness-sports-bra-tank-tops-p-24984.html)

I have below Javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery && jQuery(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        DL.items_list.initItemAttr(4, '{"sku-SV023435_B_M":"e90dfb84e30edf611e326eeb04d680de6c2de33453d563b7965b97195e855512","sku-SV023435_BL_M":"9594eec95be70e7b1710f730fdda33d96c2de33453d563b7965b97195e855512","sku-SV023435_PU_M":"b9ba865fec061c9706d2fd7ce49c0cc76c2de33453d563b7965b97195e855512"}', '{"price":"5.07","products_dropship_price":"0.0000","has_discount_price":false}', "", '{"sku-SV023435_B_M":7,"sku-SV023435_BL_M":10,"sku-SV023435_PU_M":11}', '{"image_e90dfb84e30edf611e326eeb04d680de":"http:\/\/img1.dresslink.com\/SV\/0\/SV023435-8484-SV023435-G.jpg","image_9594eec95be70e7b1710f730fdda33d9":"http:\/\/img1.dresslink.com\/SV\/0\/SV023435-8484-SV023435-G.jpg","image_b9ba865fec061c9706d2fd7ce49c0cc7":"http:\/\/img1.dresslink.com\/SV\/0\/SV023435-8484-SV023435_PU-G.jpg"}');
    }, 2000);
    var de = $('#w_pro_detail');
    de.find('#switchItem').click(function(){
        var _t = $(this);
        if(_t.is('.narrow')){
            var p_wh = _t.parent().width();
            _t.attr('class','expend').text('>>').parent().animate({left:0,opacity:1},500).css({opacity:1,paddingRight:20});
            _t.parent().find('.p_info,.size_color,.quantity').hide();
            de.css('min-width','0');
            UtilTool.setCookie('isMiniQuickShop', '1', 24);
        }else{
            _t.attr('class','narrow').text('<<').parent().animate({left:10},500);
            _t.parent().find('.p_info,.size_color,.quantity').show();
            de.css('min-width','480px');
            UtilTool.setCookie('isMiniQuickShop', '', 0);
        }

    }).end().mouseover(function(event){
        var elem = $(event.currentTarget),
            fromElem = $(event.target);
        if(elem.has(fromElem).length || fromElem.is(elem)){
            de.stop();
            de.animate({opacity:1},500);
        }

    }).mouseout(function(event){
         var elem = $(event.currentTarget),
            toElem = $(event.target);
        if(!elem.has(toElem).length || toElem.is(elem)){
            de.stop();
            de.animate({opacity:0.15},500);
        }

    });

    var isMiniQuickShop = UtilTool.getCookie('isMiniQuickShop');
    if(isMiniQuickShop == '1') {
        de.css('min-width','0');
        $('#w_pro_detail').find('#switchItem').text('>>').attr('class','expend').end().css({opacity:1,left:0,paddingRight:20}).find('.p_info,.size_color,.quantity').hide();
    }

});
</script>
```

Out of this code below json part is important for me, it has stock availability for each SKU.

```
 '{"sku-SV023435_B_M":7,"sku-SV023435_BL_M":10,"sku-SV023435_PU_M":11}'
```

Now please help me how I can get this part using PHP and preg_match or any suitable function.

Thanks!

Update:
The number os SKUs are not same , it differs from one to unlimited. here is another sample :

```
'{"sku-11430_B_S":"20","sku-11430_B_M":"17","sku-11430_B_L":"30","sku-11430_B_XS":"13","sku-11430_BL_S":"7","sku-11430_BL_M":"17","sku-11430_BL_L":"4","sku-11430_BL_XS":"16","sku-11430_O_S":"8","sku-11430_O_M":"6","sku-11430_O_L":"22","sku-11430_O_XS":"20","sku-11430_LBL_S":"27","sku-11430_LBL_M":"25","sku-11430_LBL_L":"22","sku-11430_LBL_XS":"10","sku-11430_Y_S":"24","sku-11430_Y_M":36,"sku-11430_Y_L":"20","sku-11430_Y_XS":"6","sku-11430_RR_S":"4","sku-11430_RR_M":"35","sku-11430_RR_L":"47","sku-11430_RR_XS":"6"}',
```

Comment: Are you asking for something like `[\{"sku-SV023435_B_M":(?'SVB_M'\d+),"sku-SV023435_BL_M":(?'SVBL_M'\d+),"sku-SV023435_PU_M":(?'SVPU_M'\d+)\}]`(https://regex101.com/r/xS3qN6/1)?

Comment: No, SKUs are different for each product. this page was an example only, SKU numbers are different as well , from one to about twenty! @stribizhev

Comment: And this one: [`\{"(?'SKU1'sku-\w+)":(?'SKU_1VAL'\d+),"(?'SKU2'sku-\w+)":(?'SKU_2VAL'\d+),"(?'SKU3'sku-\w+)":(?'SKU_3VAL'\d+)\}`](https://regex101.com/r/xS3qN6/3)?

Comment: The solution is much better now but the thing is number is SKUs are not always 3! it differs from one to around twenty! @stribizhev

Comment: I edited the question and added another sample. hope it helps! @stribizhev

Answer (score 0):

I suggest extracting these substrings first using `preg_match_all`, and then parse using `json`.

I assume that the JSON objects you are interested in always

- include all fields starting with `sku-`
- values are always integer

Extracting regex will then look like:

```
$re = "#\{(?:,?\"sku-\w+\":\"?\d+\"?)+\}#i";
```

[Code](http://ideone.com/ttRimt):

```
$re = "#\{(?:,?\"sku-\w+\":\"?\d+\"?)+\}#i"; 
$str = "<<<YOUR_STRING>>>"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
foreach ($matches[0] as $val)
{
   $a = $val;
   $a = json_decode($a);
   print_r($a);
}
```

Output:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [sku-11430_B_S] => 20
    [sku-11430_B_M] => 17
    [sku-11430_B_L] => 30
    [sku-11430_B_XS] => 13
    [sku-11430_BL_S] => 7
    [sku-11430_BL_M] => 17
    [sku-11430_BL_L] => 4
    [sku-11430_BL_XS] => 16
    [sku-11430_O_S] => 8
    [sku-11430_O_M] => 6
    [sku-11430_O_L] => 22
    [sku-11430_O_XS] => 20
    [sku-11430_LBL_S] => 27
    [sku-11430_LBL_M] => 25
    [sku-11430_LBL_L] => 22
    [sku-11430_LBL_XS] => 10
    [sku-11430_Y_S] => 24
    [sku-11430_Y_M] => 36
    [sku-11430_Y_L] => 20
    [sku-11430_Y_XS] => 6
    [sku-11430_RR_S] => 4
    [sku-11430_RR_M] => 35
    [sku-11430_RR_L] => 47
    [sku-11430_RR_XS] => 6
)
stdClass Object
(
    [sku-SV023435_B_M] => 7
    [sku-SV023435_BL_M] => 10
    [sku-SV023435_PU_M] => 11
)
```

This regex is a bit safer since it may match escaped entities in the `sku-` part:

```
$re = "#\{(?:,?\s*\"sku-[^\"\\]*(?:\\.[^\"\\]*)*\"\s*:\s*\"?\d+\"?\s*)+\}#i";
```

To extract all JSON objects:

```
$re = "#\{\s*\"[^\"\\]*(?:\\.[^\"\\]*)*\"\s*:\s*(?:\"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^\"\\]*)*\"|\S+)\s*\}#";
```

Comment: Does it work for you or do you need further assistance?